# Fetching numbers from a row?

Tags: excel-2007

Assuming I have the following sheet:

http://screencast.com/t/s5khEE9N1Q25

I want the sheet to return for example the 2 highest values and insert them in the corresponding cells (K to K). In this example for row 1, 400 should appear in J and 500 in K, etc.

This is just a simple version of a much wider sheet. I need it to return the 10 highest values in rows of 20 entries in the real sheet.

Is there anyway to do that without coding

Kind regards

René

Answer (score 0):

Enter in G1:

```
=IF(OR(A1=LARGE($A1:$E1,1),A1=LARGE($A1:$E1,2)),A1,"")
```

Drag to fill over/down.